# NSTextField frame automatically hugs content when superview is AVPlayerView.contentOverlayView

Tags: cocoa, avkit

I need to manually set the frame of a `NSTextField`, but it seems that when added to `AVPlayerView.contentOverlayView` the frame gets resized so that it hugs the text.

[image]

This doesn't happen when the text field is added to a simple `NSView` instead.

[image]

Is this a bug? Is there a workaround?

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        view = NSView()
        let text = NSTextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 30))
        text.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        text.isEditable = false
        text.backgroundColor = .red
        let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraph.alignment = .center
        text.attributedStringValue = NSAttributedString(string: "asdf", attributes: [.paragraphStyle: paragraph])
        view.addSubview(text)

        // commenting out the following 3 lines solves the issue
        let playerView = AVPlayerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
        view.addSubview(playerView)
        playerView.contentOverlayView!.addSubview(text)

        // uncommenting the following 5 lines also solves the issue, but the wrong text field frame is briefly visible before it resizes to the correct width
//        DispatchQueue.main.async {
//            print(text.frame)
//            text.frame.size.width = 200
//            text.removeConstraints(text.constraints)
//        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding constraints or `text.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true`?

Comment: Why didn't I think of that? Adding constraints when layout doesn't work as expected should be the first thing to try. In my case, as you suggested, setting `text.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true` was enough to prevent the automatic hugging of the text. Thanks! Please add your suggestions as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without constraints, autolayout does what it wants. Add constraints or let `NSView` translate the default autoresizing mask into constraints.